# Difference between "assent" and "consent"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *assent* and *consent*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To consent is to give permission, which could have been withheld. It implies a power relationship where the consent is granted by the party with more power.

There is the political theory that says, governments can rule only with the [consent of the governed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consent_of_the_governed). That is, the people *consent* to be governed and thus grant their power to the government.

To assent is to agree with a statement made by an equal. On the Supreme Court, one justice writes the opinion of the majority, to which other justices *assent*. Those that disagree are said to dissent, that is to disagree.

So, consent = permission while assent = agreement. A subtle distinction perhaps, but a useful one.

Answer (score 7):

My brain's immediate shorthand response is:

"assent" = "agree"

"consent" = "allow"

Answer (score 1):

["Approve (of)," "assent," "consent," and "grant"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/18724/50720) may help. Some extracts:

http://www.translegal.com/common-mistakes/assent-vs-consent:

> In legal English, consent and assent are often used interchangeably. There is a subtle difference though.
>
> The term **assent** connotes a positive and voluntary agreement both as a noun and a verb.
>   “Assent to a proposal of marriage.”
>
> The term **consent** is neutral in connotation and can apply even when the agreement is given reluctantly.
>   “The employee consented to the non-compete clause being included in her employment agreement.”

http://grammarist.com/usage/assent-consent/:

> **Assent** and **consent** are mostly synonymous—they both mean to agree or to give permission—but **assent** connotes a greater degree of enthusiasm, and **consen**t often comes with reluctance. In law and government, **consent** is more readily denied, while **assent** is often a mere formality.

Answer (score -1):

*Assent* can also carry an official connotation, as of a government agency or official expressing approval. Otherwise they are synonymous.