# Approve or Approve of?

Tags: grammar

What is the correct way of saying the sentence?

My teacher doesn't approve of the first example that I have listed.

My teacher doesn't approve the first example that I have listed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Approve (of)," "assent," "consent," and "grant"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18724/approve-of-assent-consent-and-grant)

Answer (score 5):

Stretching the [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/363076/186126) of Deadrat little further:

For Op's given examples:

> **My teacher doesn't approve of the first example that I have listed.**
>
> Means:
>
> The teacher does not **agree with** the first example.

While

> **My teacher doesn't approve the first example that I have listed.**
>
> Means
>
> The teacher doesn't **accept** the example.

Comment: But in the recent campaign, "approve" was used to mean "agree with" - "I'm Jane Doe,  and I approve this message."

Comment: @Mike Jones One swallow doesn't make a summer.

Answer (score 3):

*Approve* has the meaning of agreement, but with the preposition, it means agree with:

> I **approved** **of** your decision.

Without the preposition, it means agree to:

> The executives committee **approved** your budget.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's not clear from the previous answers, you should used *approve of* in this context. If you're going for more of an "acceptance" meaning, just use *accept*:

> The examiner didn't accept the first example that I have listed as a
>   correct one.